# Menu links not clickable

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, menu

I have defined in the code for a link to go to a page, but it is not going anywhere when I click it.

If you go to this page: http://www.davidhechtkitchens.com/ and try to click on "Portfolio" in the top navigation it does nothing. If you look at the code you'll see that it's defined to go to portfolio.html.

This problem only seems to be in effect when there is a sub-menu underneith the top link. If I remove the sub-menu from "Portfolio" it works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have some kind of script active that prevents the default action,

While checking the source code, When I click on the button it adds a class to the anchor. (In most cases this is made to make it work on mobile devices)

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix Just add a class of .menu-link to all the links that you want that are not sub menu links. You can use whatever class you want but make sure that class is only on the href's you want to actually use this. Also don't forget to put this AFTER your Jquery include.

```
<script>
$(".menu-link").on("click", function(){

//get this clicked link
var link = $(this).attr('href');

//go to link clicked
window.location = link;

});
</script>
```